# How to bake using Principled + cycles under reasonable time? GPU + CPU = Instant crash

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shaders, baking, opencl

Here is the deal, I'm using principled shader to bake a simple object, it works is great but I've waited 36 Hours and it was at 70%.

The object is a car with only 13K polys and I've separated the materials for each object that uses it, and I try to bake a single object/material per time.

I have a Ryzen 1600 and a RX 580 with 8GB, I have tiles at center and at 512px,

Light Patch at 6 bounces (max) and render samples at 256. Caustics Disabled.

Not sure why it is taking ages to render on 2.79B and why it crashes intantly when trying to use hybrid CPU+GPU OpenCL render on newer 2.79 and 2.8.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

I have also tried with only roughness and diffuse and nothing changed.

Answer (score 2):

OK, looks like todays (07/07/2018) Blender 2.79 is baking using GPU + CPU without crashing. Plus I've unchecked the square samples and now it baked the same file with same node setup in 40min instead of 44 hours.

very nice!

[image]